# How to raise the buffer value with ethtool on the network

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ifconfig

It occurred the Dropped packet with checking ifconfig command tool. The Dropped counted up with a lot of volumes.

```
$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:イーサネット  ハードウェアアドレス 4c:72:b9:f6:27:a8
          inetアドレス:192.168.1.102  ブロードキャスト:192.168.1.255  マスク:255.255.255.0
          inet6アドレス: fe80::4e72:b9ff:fef6:27a8/64 範囲:リンク
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  メトリック:1
          RXパケット:2745254558 エラー:0 **損失:1003363** オーバラン:0 フレーム:0
          TXパケット:7633337281 エラー:0 損失:0 オーバラン:0 キャリア:0
          衝突(Collisions):0 TXキュー長:1000
          RXバイト:1583378766375 (1.5 TB)  TXバイト:10394167206386 (10.3 TB)
```

So I'll use ethtool to raise the network buffer value.

```
$ sudo ethtool -g eth0
Ring parameters for eth0:
Cannot get device ring settings: Operation not supported
```

I can't confirm eth0 status.
And, I don't understand what the ring is.

Answer (score 1):

is this Virtual Machine ?

So from the symbols you pasted I assume there is drop on the RX. 
You need to rise the RX ring buffer with `ethtool -G eth0 rx 4096`

Show more info `ethtool -i eth0` and `netstat -s`

There is a lot more tuning to eth0 than just ring buffers.

Try to rise  `net.core.netdev_max_backlog`.
Check it with `sysctl net.core.netdev_max_backlog` and set the new value with `sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=numberhere`.

EDIT:
Please also show card HW info
`sudo lshw -C network`

google for *Cannot get device ring settings r8169*

Comment: No, it's a simple physical server without VM.

Comment: $ sudo ethtool -i eth0
driver: r8169
version: 2.3LK-NAPI
firmware-version: rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw
bus-info: 0000:08:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no

Comment: How can i provide a direct answer when the information provided by the OP is not enough ?